# Is there a failed block for Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire with Swift kind of this way:

```
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
    .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
    .response {
        (request, responseJSON, data, error) in [..and so on]
```

Now I wonder how I can execute some code in case the server is e.g. completely down. Something like a failed block in ObjC.
I know that I can call something like this to get an error code:

```
        if let response = responseJSON {
            var statusCode = response.statusCode
            println("-->statusCode: \(statusCode)")

        }
```

But in the case that I can't reach the server, the .response closure won't execute, so there is no error message.

How is this handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't reach the server, you will receive a `NSURLErrorDomain` error via the `error` variable in the closure.

Comment: You are right. I just didn't wait long enough until the timeout occured